# Multiple step from saved using symfony2 with next and back feature

Tags: symfony

Please help me what is best possible approaches do it.  craue/formflow-bundle
 is not usefull.
I have an application form that have four steps that are Business Information,Personal Information,Financial Information last is Agreement form.I want Next, save continue and back button on each form. 
I am new in symfony2.

Please help me .

Comment: First of all you are to read a documentation about forms in `Symfony`: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html

Comment: already read forms and form collections but unable to find how to break entity in multiple step in doctrine because persist validate all entity data

Comment: Read about Validation Groups http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups

Comment: In a previous project I had the same problem and the (really good) craue/formflow-bundle don't satisfy my needed. So use an Entity with all field and every action step persist the entity. I manage the step with different form type and manage the validation with the validation groups. Nothing of magic. My Two cents.

Comment: @Matteo How do you handle the back button? If the user clicks back on step 2, he goes to step 1 where he expects his already existing object to be present and not create a new one again.

Comment: @utkarsh2k2 at every step change, i persist the state and put in the url the id of the entity, so the back button point to an url to the step1 with the id of the entity (like an edit action). If the user use the back of the browser this trick doesnt' work. Hoenewer I suggest to handle the behavior in the frontend (Like a SPA) and made a final single api call